# Testing Rails Controllers and Middleware- Functional vs. Integration testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, integration-testing

## Background

I have a legacy Rails 3.2 app which I'm converting from a homegrown testing solution to a rails one (currently MiniTest).  The app is a JSON api with a single endpoint, so testing is very simple at this point.  We build a (relatively complex) json payload and then make assertions against the response.

### What I've done so far

The old testing solution was to fire HTTP requests over the wire (using an HTTP gem) at a separately-running instance of the server.  This ran it through the entire stack, including the middleware stack, eventually hitting `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` which makes the `params` hash available to controllers.

I converted tests to be subclasses of `ActionController::TestCase` so that only a single rails instance (the test instance) is running.  I then removed the HTTP gem so that I could use the `ActionController::TestCase#post` method to send the json payload.  That's where things fell apart

### The Problem

It seems like only rails integration tests exercise the middleware stack, while functional tests are more like unit tests for the controller.  Thus, behind `ActionController::TestCase#post` is the [`#paramify_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L440) method, which looks like it's mocking out the params hash with some logic that's *like* the [logic in `ParamsParser`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb#L25) but has some differences.  Most importantly, when I try to send a float in my params hash, it gets converted to a string.  ParamsParser correctly put the float in `params`.  I do a bunch of math in my controller, but math doesn't work so well when you're getting passed (incorrectly) a string, instead of a number.

### My Question(s)

- Is there a way to run an `ActionController::TestCase` with the rails middleware stack handling things?
- Am I using the wrong tool, and should instead be using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`?  The examples on the rails guides for `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` look like they're made for user workflows, more akin to cucumber/capybara scripts than firing single requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing to dive into the rails source, it's clear that using a functional test is the **wrong** thing to do here.  Integration tests are what I should be using if the middleware stack is important.

I believe [this rails bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13135) touches on the same sort of issues that I'm encountering<strike>, but it has gone stale, so I don't know what resolution there there might be.</strike> and it has [been resolved for Rails 5, but not Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13135#issuecomment-138808575).